# VBA Function to format parts of a string as subscripts

Tags: excel, vba, function, string-formatting

I have some text that I'm using to keep track of a bunch of variables in a long equation. Here's a short sample:

[image]

### **Requirements**

I'm trying to make a VBA function that will take three cells as input and return what you see in the **Term** column (column D).

It will take the **Coef** cell and format it such that everything after the first character is subscripted, then do the same for the **Variable** cell.

If the value of **Coef Value** > 0, then the function should return the concatenation `subscripted_Coef & "*" & subscripted_Variable` (where `subscripted_Coef` and `subscripted_Variable` are pseudo-code); Otherwise it should return 0.

### **Problem**

My issue is when I call the function in a cell (e.g. cell E3), I get an error message in Visual Basic:

[image]

Clicking OK highlights `Public Function ConstructTerm(coef_cell, var_cell, coef_value)` in yellow in Visual Basic.

I'm very new to VBA so at this point I am lost. I was able to make a macro to apply the proper formatting to a selection of cells with help from another StackOverflow post (didn't copy down the share link though), but I'm having trouble converting that into a function. I won't post that macro code for sake of length of this post, but I can if needed.

Cell E2 shows an IF-statement that I used before to get the required output, but it doesn't apply the subscript formatting that I want. It shows the logic I'm wanting though, with the exception of the ISBLANK() portion (I can do without that).

### **Code so far**

```
Public Function ConstructTerm(coef_cell, var_cell, coef_value)
' =================================================================================================
' For a selection of cells combine the coefficient and variable parts to make the term for that
' contribution to the larger equation. This function will later be called to create the entire 
' equation when a button is pressed in the Excel Worksheet. 
'
' INPUTS:
'   - coef_cell: (String) The cell containing the string for the coefficient part
'   - var_cell: (String) The cell containing the string for the variable part
'   - coef_value: (Double) The value of the coefficient. If value = 0 then return 0 instead of the
'                  concatenated string
'
' OUTPUTS:
'   - (String) The concatenated string in the format <coef_cell>*<var_cell> with the proper subscripts
'      on both the coef_cell and var_cell.
' =================================================================================================
Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String

s1 = make_subscript(coef_cell)
s2 = make_subscript(var_cell)
If coef_value = 0 Then
    ConstructTerm = 0
Else
    ConstructTerm = s1 & "*" & s2
End If

End Function


Public Function MakeSubscript(cell_str)
' =================================================================================================
' Make all characters after the 1st character in a string subscripted. This function is a variation
' on the subprocedure named make_subscript()
'
' INPUTS:
'   - cell_str: (String) The string that needs to have all characters after the first character subscripted
'
' OUTPUTS:
'   - (String) The contents of the string with all the characters after the first subscripted
' =================================================================================================
With cell_str.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
    .Subscript = False
End With
With cell_str.Characters(Start:=2).Font
    .Subscript = True
End With
make_subscript = cell_str
End Function
```

### **Update**

Here is the code that I ended up with to do what I wanted. Thanks to [Ron Rosenfeld for his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64807624/11895567)

**Edit:** *Totally forgot about the ISBLANK portion of the original code, not a huge deal. It updates automatically so if a change is made then the change is reflected automatically.*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' =================================================================================================
' Use event code to automatically apply the proper formatting to the 'Term' column.
'
' When any of the cells in columns for coefficient, variable, or coefficient value are changed the
' cell to the right of column coefficient value is updated with the string representation of the
' product of coef and variable cells for that row; the numbers will be properly subscripted.
'
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' *************************************************************************************************
' * WARNING: ASSUMES A RIDIG LAYOUT OF THE DATA! DO NOT ATTEMPT TO USE ON ANYTHING OTHER THAN     *
' *          workbook_name.xlsm WORKSHEET [worksheet name].                               *
' *************************************************************************************************
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' This code must be placed in the worksheet code module of the worksheet containing the target
' data. For more info on worksheet code see https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' TODO
' -  Need to have the cell retain whatever border/shading formatting it had before the change to
'    one of the three columns occurs. Low priority though.
' - When changing values in one of the three columns, the values entered don't appear in the cell
'   as they are being entered... but they show up in the formula bar properly. Weird...
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' Code source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64807624/11895567
'
' Minor modifications made for compatability with production worksheet instead of test worksheet
' and other minor code formatting changes to suit my preferences. (, on 11-12-2020)
'
' Created on 11-12-2020
' =================================================================================================
Dim rngToCheck As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim sRes As String
Dim I As Long

Dim coef_col As Integer
Dim coef_val_col As Integer
Dim variable_col As Integer

coef_col = 5                ' Coef column is Column E
variable_col = coef_col + 1 ' Variable column is Column F
coef_val_col = coef_col + 2 ' Coef Value column is Column G

' determine last filled in row of column E, and expand to E:G
Set rngToCheck = Range(Cells(1, coef_col), Cells(Rows.Count, coef_col).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
If Not Intersect(rngToCheck, Target) Is Nothing Then    ' Is the changed cell within the rngToCheck
    Application.EnableEvents = False                    ' Disable event checking so as not to retrigger
                                                        '     when writing results
    For Each C In Intersect(rngToCheck, Target)         ' subscript the appropriate characters
        With C
            If Cells(C.Row, coef_val_col) <> 0 Then
                s1 = Cells(C.Row, coef_col)
                s2 = Cells(C.Row, variable_col)
                sRes = s1 & "*" & s2
                With Cells(C.Row, coef_val_col + 1)
                    .ClearFormats
                    .Value = sRes
                    For I = 1 To Len(sRes)
                        If IsNumeric(Mid(sRes, I, 1)) Then
                            .Characters(I, 1).Font.Subscript = True
                        End If
                    Next I
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next C
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True 're-enable event code; if macro exits prematurely, this won't happen
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is a UDF (VBA function that you use as formula) is not allowed to change cells or formats it can only return a value. And second thing is that a part of a formula result cannot be formatted differently from the rest of a cell. • So what you try cannot work. Excel does not support this as of the 2 given reasons. • `.Characters` works only on cells with constant values but not on cells that contain formulas.

Comment: ^ One potential solution is to use a `Sub` here then, instead of a UDF.

Comment: Yes, that's it the only solution is a button calling a `Sub` to do that. But with formulas and functions it is impossible due to Excel's limitations.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ dang... well maybe I can use this to find a solution. I'm a python person so VBA is a bit wild to me haha. I'll keep working on it and post whatever solution I end up with if nobody else has anything. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use event code to accomplish your goals.

For example, install this module in the **worksheet code module** of the worksheet where your table is located.

- The code is triggered on a change in cells in the first three columns
- Then, depending on the contents of column 3, it will do the subscripting according to a scheme which subscripts digits (you may want to change that)
- *my code is not as well annotated as yours, but you should be able to get the picture and make any appropriate changes*
- *Also, there are some additions that should be made*

  - *If you delete the contents of column 1, it gets removed from rngToCheck, so might want to blank everything below rngToCheck as a first step*
  - *might need a different algorithm for determining subscripted characters*

***Edit to blank cell if `0` or blank in column 3***

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range, C As Range
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, sRes As String
    Dim I As Long
    
    
'determine last filled in row of column A, and expand to A:C
Set rngToCheck = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)

'Is the changed cell within the rngToCheck
If Not Intersect(rngToCheck, Target) Is Nothing Then

    'Disable event checking so as not to retrigger when writing results
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'subscript the appropriate characters
    For Each C In Intersect(rngToCheck, Target)
        With C
            If Cells(C.Row, 3) <> 0 Then
                s1 = Cells(C.Row, 1)
                s2 = Cells(C.Row, 2)
                sRes = s1 & "*" & s2
                
                With Cells(C.Row, 4)
                    .ClearFormats
                    .Value = sRes
                    For I = 1 To Len(sRes)
                        If IsNumeric(Mid(sRes, I, 1)) Then
                            .Characters(I, 1).Font.Subscript = True
                        End If
                    Next I
                End With
            Else
                Cells(C.Row, 4) = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next C
End If

're-enable event code
'if macro exits prematurely, this won't happen
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!